# How should I expose an enum?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, properties

Here's my situation.

I have a library that has a set of enums that I need to use.

```
public enum showtype
{
  comedy = 1001, horror = 1002, mystery = 1003, action = 1004;
}
```

This library is being referenced by another library that I created.
My library is referenced by more than one console based app.

I need to assign the show type directly from the console based app.

Comment: I think I know what you're asking, but could you walk through an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty simple. Add a reference to the library that contains the Enum inside your console application.

Answer (score 2):

A few additional notes to clarify what may be going on:

- If your application references a library that references the library with the `enum`, then this is not enough. You need to directly reference the library with the `enum`.
- You should also make sure that you open the namespace where the `enum` is located using the `using` construct.

Answer (score 1):

Your enum is already exposed. Add the reference and you're ready to go.